# Creating a simple Drupal 8 custom service - argument should be an instance of a class, recognised as an array

Tags: services, debugging, dependency-injection

I'm kind of new to Drupal 8 development and object-oriented PHP in general. I've been trying to make a simple custom block module, which includes a service with simple dependency injection. However, I can't seem to figure out why the construct method does not receive an appropriate parameter - been staring at the code for hours. My code:

**event_countdown.services.yml**

```
services:
  event_countdown.date_calculator:
    class: Drupal\event_countdown\DateCalculator
```

**event_countdown.routing.yml**

```
event_countdown.content:
  defaults:
    _title: 'Event Countdown'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
```

**src/DateCalculator.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\event_countdown;

class DateCalculator {

  // forms the block's output based on given date
  public function daysUntilEventStarts($date) {
    // get difference in days between now and the given date
    $difference = $this->getDifferenceInDaysFromCurrentDate($date);
      // if event date is in the future
      if($difference >= 1) {
        return "Days left until the event starts: " . $difference;
      // if event date and current date are on the same day
      } else if($difference == 0) {
        return "The event is in progress.";
      // if event date is in the past
      } else {
        return "The event has already ended.";
      }
  }

  // calculates difference in days between now and given date
  public function getDifferenceInDaysFromCurrentDate($date) {
    // current time
    $now = time();
    // event datetime field converted to timestamp
    $event_date = strtotime($date);
    // timestamp difference
    $difference = $event_date - $now;
    // timestamp difference rounded down to days
    return round($difference / (60 * 60 * 24));
  }

}
```

**src/Plugin/Block/EventCountdownBlock.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\event_countdown\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\event_countdown\DateCalculator;


/**
 * Provides an event countdown block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "event_countdown_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Event countdown block"),
 *   category = @Translation("Event countdown block"),
 * )
 */

class EventCountdownBlock extends BlockBase {

  protected $dateCalculator;

   public function __construct(DateCalculator $dateCalculator) {
     $this->dateCalculator = $dateCalculator;
   }

   public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
     return new static($container->get('event_countdown.date_calculator'));
   }

   public function build() {

      // get current node based on route
      $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

      //check whether node type equals 'event' - if it does, get text output, otherwise display an error message
      if($node->getType() == "event") {
        // get datetime value from node
        $date = $node->field_event_date->value;
        // call service method to calculate difference in days
        $output = $this->dateCalculator->daysUntilEventStarts($date);
      } else {
        // display error
        $output = "Woops! This block is intended only for event pages.";
      }

      return array(
        // output
        '#markup' => $output,
        // prevent block caching
        '#cache' => [
          'max-age' => 0,
          ],
      );
  }

}
```

**The error I get in Drupal logs is:**

`Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\event_countdown\Plugin\Block\EventCountdownBlock::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\event_countdown\DateCalculator, array given, called in D:\drupal8\devdesktop\drupal-8.5.1\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory.php on line 25 and defined in Drupal\event_countdown\Plugin\Block\EventCountdownBlock->__construct() (line 24 of D:\drupal8\devdesktop\drupal-8.5.1\modules\custom\event_countdown\src\Plugin\Block\EventCountdownBlock.php) #0 D:\drupal8\devdesktop\drupal-8.5.1\core\includes\bootstrap.inc(582): _drupal_error_handler_real(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', 'D:\\drupal8\\devd...', 24, Array) #1`

I would appreciate any sort of help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins aren't naturally container-aware, so your `create` method is never called. The default plugin factory passes a configuration array as the first argument to your constructor, hence the error.

You can make the plugin container-aware by implementing [`ContainerFactoryPluginInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/8.2.x). For example:

```
class EventCountdownBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, DateCalculator $dateCalculator) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->dateCalculator = $dateCalculator;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('event_countdown.date_calculator')
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ah, everything makes so much more sense now. Your suggestion worked, thank you very much :)